# Universities accepting non-cs background students to masters programs in cs

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science

My greetings to all users.

I am a student with my UG in Electronics and Communications, planning to enroll in a masters program in computer science (preferably with thesis, but open to coursework option as well). In my UG, I had the following courses related to mathematics and computer science:

Maths:
1. Calculus
2. Discrete Mathematics
3. Optimization techniques
4. Numerical Analysis
5. Information theory and coding

Computers:
1. Computer Programming (basic C)
2. Computer Architecture

Apart from these, I had Data communication also.

Apart from US universities which offer flexibility to non-cs background students to enroll in MS in CS, do **Canadian** and **European** universities offer this flexibility also? I visited some university websites, and they have listed some courses like Data structures and Algorithms, DBMS, Operating systems, which I did not have in my UG. Does this mean elimination therein or do I still have a chance?

Answer (score 1):

I would find it difficult even for a university in the US to accept a student for masters studies without, at least, data structures and algorithms. It is one of the most important courses in the curriculum and is where many people drop out of studies because of its difficulty and because it is a stepping stone into more theoretical CS (which is what graduate studies consists of!).

Basic C programming isn't really enough for a masters program. I am not an expert on the UK or European systems but from what I know I would say that your chances are very slim- though not impossible. If I were you- I would take more prereq courses that you see commonly listed on websites (especially data structures and algorithms- I'd also recommend an advanced algorithms course) and then apply as that would maximize your chances of admissions.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Elimination is perhaps too strong, but you will have a hard time selling yourself to an admissions committee without the named courses at least. All of your classmates will likely have all of those skills and so the courses you take will assume them. It would be a rough time for you even if you were admitted.

But in a lot of places you will get a chance to make your case. These would be smaller schools who don't have to depend on rules to weed out the masses and have the ability to look at each candidate.

But I wouldn't give much encouragement.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I would like to mention here that I am enrolled at an Indian central govt institution for a six months course covering algorithms, dbms , computer networks and some others. Do universities consider such courses as remedial work or do they not?

Comment: I just think you need to make your own case. They are more interested, in almost all cases, in what you know, not how you learned it. Having a transcript of some sort helps you demonstrate that. "Remedial" is a bad word. It usually implies some past failure. That isn't your situation. You just followed a different path. Your "encouragement score" just improved. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For some of the UK universities, you can take the Master Program based on your background.  Even if you do not meet some of the criteria (maybe you did not take DBMS for example), you are still eligible to apply.  Just email the student administration office, they will give you advice and guidance.  Don't worry!

[Rules are dead]

Cheers!